# Extract unsubscribes

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-extract, unsubscribe

I need to export all our unsubscribes in Marketing Cloud and I'm having trouble doing this.

I have tried exporting All Subscribers, but due to the volume of records ~15M Marketing Cloud takes almost an entire day and eventually times out.

I have also tried using the unsubscribe Data View but that only gives you 6 months' worth of data.

What other options do I have for extracting all our unsubscribes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In All Subscribers, you can search by Subscriber Status.  I searched all 'Unsubscribed' and was able to extract just unsubscribers with their unsubscribed date and reason.

Answer (score 4):

Query the `_Subscribers` data view. [Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) is not restricted to 6 months as other data views are.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE Status = 'Unsubscribed'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Josh.  My unsubscribers are kept at the child BU level and I believe the _Subscribers data view only exists at the parent BU level.  When I try to run the query at child BU level it returns 0 records.

Comment: Yes, child BU is an important detail to leave out of your original question. I have had this same issue before with a child BU, so I share your frustration at what you would expect to be a simple and obvious task. I'm sorry I don't have a solution that addresses the child BU scenario. Personally, I would be contacting support at this point. If you find out a specific answer, update here and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 4):

To get the statuses from a child business unit, run a tracking extract and include 'Extract Subscribers' and 'Include All Subscribers'. Typically I'll add this to an automation that then imports the extract file into a data extension that you can then query/filter from easily.

[image]

Your extract should include the following fields:

[image]

Comment: That's what I did.  I just retried again today but I'm still not getting any unsubscribers. I'm getting Active, Held, Bounced but no Unsubscribed.  I followed your steps except I extracted to a csv file into the SFTP.  I did not import into a DE as I figured that wouldn't impact the results.

Comment: Are you running this from a child business unit? And the 'DateUnsubscribed' field is null for all records too?

Comment: Actually it does come through with the unsubscribe status.  The value is 'unsub' and I was filtering/searching on 'unsubscribe' - sorry my bad!  The count is a problem though because it's only giving me half of the unsubscribe count Support gave me for that BU.  I have since found another method of using the AllSubscribers extract that has resolved this for me.

Answer (score 2):

Marketing Cloud unsubscribe has 2 settings:

1. Unsubscribe subscribers from all Business Units
2. Unsubscribe subscribers from this specific BU only.

Assuming option 1 is in place the unsubscribe is captured in `_subscribers` and spans across all BUS.

to find this you can run the query

```
select subscriberkey
from
_subscribers
where
status = 'unsubscribed'
```

However if option 2 is in place, unsubscribes specific to that BU are captured in a different data view:

`_businessunitunsubscribes`

The query you would then use is:

```
select subscriberkey,
from _businessunitunsubscribes 
where 
businessunitid = 'yourbusinessunitid'
```

This will pull unsubscribes that happened as a result of the subscriber unsubbing from a specific BU only because option 2 was in place

[image: unsubscribe settings]

`businessunitunsubscribes` is the data view used to understand unsubscribes from a specific BU when the unsubscribe from this BU only feature is enabled
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I have reached out to Support and the only way to extract this data is via tracking extract.  Unfortunately, tracking extracts can only capture 90 days of data at a time so you need to set up multiple extracts.

Comment: The length of time only matters if you need to capture specific events in the report. You can set the length to 1 day and run the report with 'All Subscribers' checked, it will run and return your list of All Subscribers with their current opt-in status. These results are business unit specific, so you would likely need to run it in each business if you need the status specific to each business unit for your subscribers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I have just tried this and unfortunately it returns all subscriber statuses except unsubscribes.  I believe unsubscribes are kept in another table not accessible via the UI.

Comment: It should... I'll do a reply with screenshots